# I can't call a GET on external site but in Postman I can

Tags: .net, postman

I am new to programming. Although I have no problems doing CRUD with Postman, react/next.js, and .NET locally (using local bases, get, post, put, delete, etc.), now I have to do the same with an external site and I can't do it.

This is the situation:
Using Postman I have the URL and a token and by doing a GET I receive a successful response. What should the example be like in my API for this to work? Currently it gives me a `404` which means that the page does not exist, but using the same data in Postman it does. That's what I don't understand and it confuses me.

Example of my controller in .NET:

```
[HttpGet("externalSite")] [Authorize] public async Task<IActionResult> callOtherSite(){ try
     {
         HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "asasasasEXAMPLEasasasas");
         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://apirenaper.idear.gov.ar/CHUTROFINAL/apidatos/test/aviso_fallecimiento_clientes_registrados.php");
         if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
             var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             var benefList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<benef>>(json);

             return Ok(benefList);
         } else {
             return StatusCode(400, "errror");
         }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         // Logear el error
         // ...

         // Devolver un error
         return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684484/posting-to-external-api-throws-cors-but-it-works-from-postman

Comment: Can you show us the details from Postman too so that we may compare the requests?