# get image size (kb) with javascript with out loading it

Tags: javascript, image

Is there any way to get image size (kb) before loading it in browser by java script ?
for example there is an image in this address : "mysite.com/content/sample.jpg"
now how can we understand how much is the size (kb) of this image?

Comment: Do you mean the dimension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: Depending on how much you control the client you can use HEAD to get the header which in many cases will include the content-length

Comment: exact duplicate of [Ajax HEAD request via Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715223/ajax-head-request-via-javascript-jquery)

Comment: What I mean was the size of image in KB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it like below

```
 window.onload = function() {
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    var info = "Image Info:<br>Width: "+this.width+", Height: "+this.height;
    document.getElementById("imageInfo").innerHTML = info;
  }
  image.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg';
}
```

Here is the sample - `http://plnkr.co/edit/X1cqZYv93FzK4zC5kRE7?p=preview`

Answer (score 0):

If it's only ever a jpeg, you can just load the first chunk of the file which contains the EXIF metadata. That metadata contains width and height most of the time, although you can't be 100% certain that it's there or that it's correct. But it's probably your best bet. There are a couple of nice EXIF libraries in Javascript, and I've used this one: https://github.com/bwindels/exif-parser

It still requires you to make an HTTP request for it though, so if that's what you're worried about, there's no way to avoid it.